# Find the Number of Distinct Colour

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is Question which i have attend during a competition but i could not solve it.
Question:
Given an undirected graph having `N` vertices and M edges. Each edge is colored by one of the color from set `{1,...C}` . There are `q` queries in the form of pair of integers `x` and `y`. For a given query , find the number of distinct colors which are `present on each simple path from vertex  to vertex` .

Input:

```
5 4 4  // N,M,C
1 2 2  // U and V Nodes have Colour C
1 3 1
2 4 2
4 5 3
5      // Q
4 1    // X,Y
5 4
5 2
2 3
5 4
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2
1
```

For the third query, there is only one path from vertex 5 to 5vertex , which is {5,4,2}, which contains two distinct colors i.e.{3,2} .

How to Solve this question [Full Problem Statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/sears-dots-arrows/challenges/simple-paths) ?
Constrains:

```
1<C<40
N and M are in order 10^5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A color `C` is present on each simple path from `u` to `v`if and only if:

1. There is a path between `u` and `v`.
2. There is no path between `u` and `v` in the graph where all edges of color `C` are removed. (Proof: if there is no path in a graph without edges of this color, each path from `u` to `v` in the original graph contains at least one edge of this color. Conversely, if every simple path contains an edge of a specific color, its removal would clearly disconnect these two vertices).

This observation leads to a following solution:

1. Find connected components in the original graph (by using, for instance, depth-first search).
2. For each color `1 <= c <= C`, remove all edges of the color `c` and find connected components in the new graph.
3. If `x` and `y` are in different components in the original graph, the answer to an `(x, y)` query is 0. Otherwise, it's equal to the number of such colors `c` that `x` and `y` are in different components in the graph without edges of the color `c`.

The time complexity is `O((N + M) * (C + 1) + Q * C)` (the first term corresponds to `C + 1` depth-first searches. The second one corresponds to the iteration over all colors for each query).